# How to fix 'ERROR SqlExceptionHelper Column 'cardinalidadid' not found' error in jpa

Tags: sql, jpa, entity

I want to map an entity, which has a relationship with another table, but when mapping that relationship, it doesn't find the "Cardinality" column.

This is the code:

Entity elemento:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "elemento")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="clave", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length=10)

public class Elemento implements Serializable, GenericInterface {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "clave", insertable = false)
private String clave;

@Column(name = "numero")
private String numero;

@Column(name = "nombre")
private String nombre;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "Proyectoid")
private Proyecto proyecto;

@Column(name = "descripcion")
private String descripcion;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "EstadoElementoid", referencedColumnName="id")
private EstadoElemento estadoElemento;
```

Entity actor:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "actor")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "Elementoid", referencedColumnName = "id")
@DiscriminatorValue("ACT")

public class Actor extends Elemento implements Serializable, GenericInterface, ElementoInterface {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "Cardinalidadid", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Cardinalidad cardinalidad;
```

This is the description of the tables:

TABLE ACTOR:

```
    | actor | CREATE TABLE `actor` (
    `otraCardinalidad` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Elementoid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `Cardinalidadid` int(11) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`Elementoid`),
     KEY `FKActor872913` (`Cardinalidadid`),
     KEY `FKActor148309` (`Elementoid`),
     CONSTRAINT `FKActor148309` FOREIGN KEY (`Elementoid`) REFERENCES 
     `elemento` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
     CONSTRAINT `FKActor872913` FOREIGN KEY (`Cardinalidadid`) REFERENCES 
     `cardinalidad` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

TABLE CARDINALIDAD

```
     | cardinalidad | CREATE TABLE `cardinalidad` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `nombre` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     UNIQUE KEY `uniqueCardinalidad` (`nombre`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

This error appears

```
    02:57:43.663 [qtp1469821799-35] DEBUG 
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection - 
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@48c2c8ce handling a 
    throwable. java.sql.SQLException: Column 'cardinalidadid' not found.
```